# Can't import RKRequestSerialization.h for RestKit

Tags: iphone, restkit

I'm using XCode 4.3. I can import:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

but for some reason it will fail to find:

```
#import <RestKit/Network/RKRequestSerialization.h>
```

The install instructions were written for XCode 4.2 so there was a mismatch regarding how to setup the Derived Data Location. XCode 4.3 has more options and I chose selected the "Unique" radio button selection. Is there something else I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, maybe. Apparently in v0.10.0 of RestKit you can access all the headers from RestKit root:

```
#import <RestKit/RKRequestSerialization.h>
```

Looked at the build results and found the copy command was not copying it to RestKit/Network folder anymore.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue on v0.25.0 & cocapods version 0.38.0. Any idea?